# Inconsistent behavior selecting a text region within emacs

Tags: emacs, selection, region

I am trying to narrow down the causality for intermittent behavior that I am experiencing in Emacs.

In both cases below, I am hitting `C-<space>` to set the mark, subsequently followed up by one or more `C-n`'s to move down lines to select a region. The trouble is that it doesn't seem to always work in the same manner, as shown in the two gifs below:

Expected behavior:

[image: selectRegionWorks]

But what I am often seeing:

[image: selectRegionFails]

While this may be difficult to remotely diagnose, any help directing me in the right direction wrt to resolving this inconsistent behavior would be much appreciated. I am not an expert in Emacs and Elisp but can stumble my way around. I know there's not too much context here, but would this result from something odd happening within my .emacs? Or would it be more likely to stem from modes clashing? Fww, it has happened frequently in other major modes and is repeatable with the similar key sequence of consecutive `C-N`'s

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're not hitting `C-SPC` twice in a row? That will give you the behavior you see. (Except that it seems to flash selection of the first row.) Possibly something in code you are using here raises an error after/while selecting the first line, which essentially does a quit (`C-g`).

Comment: Do you see this when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, recursively bisect your init file to locate the culprit. Once you've narrowed it down, if things are still not clear then post a step-by-step recipe to reproduce it, starting with `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly about higlighting the region. However, there are many commands and variables which may affect this. No way to decide it from the pictures given. Suggest to send a bug report, which will include the settings and last commands called, so you may get help even in case of user-error.